# После выполнения скрипта необходимо прекратить загрузку страницы

Tags: javascript, css

При открытии страницы в браузере Chrome необходимо выполнить весь код до моего скрипта, который потом прекратит выполнение загрузки страницы, но стили, указанные до скрипта, почему-то не срабатывают.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
 body {
  background-color: tomato;
 } 
</style>
<script>
var brow = ["Chrome", "Edge"];
var b, ua = navigator.userAgent;
 for (var i = 0; i < brow.length; i++) {
  if (ua.indexOf(brow[i]) > -1) {
   b = brow[i];
   break;
  }
 }
 
 
 if (b === "Chrome") {
  alert("Пожалуйста, откройте наш сайт в любом другом браузере, спасибо!");
  if(window.stop !== undefined) {
   window.stop();
  } else if (document.execCommand !== undefined) {
   document.execCommand("Stop", false);
  } 
 } 
 else if (b === "Edge") {
  alert("Пожалуйста, откройте наш сайт в любом другом браузере, спасибо!");
  if(window.stop !== undefined) {
   window.stop();
  } else if (document.execCommand !== undefined) {
   document.execCommand("Stop", false);
  }
 }
</script>

<body>
 
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, inventore?</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы остановили загрузку body, а стили до скрипта именно для body. Body отсутствует в DOM, соответственно  и стили для него не работают. Или я не понял вопрос?

Comment: Сглупил, неправильно вставил код, так то все работает с цветом. Но сейчас я поместил скрипт после body, а в style указал body {background-image: url(main.jpg);} и почему-то изображение не грузится. В чем может быть ошибка? Изображение в одной папке с этой страницей.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это потому, что скрипт обрывает загрузку изображения. Нужно поставить тайм аут в пару сек.

Comment: function image(){
 //сюда вставь код скрипта
}
setTimeout(image, 2000);

Comment: Действительно помогло, но теперь то, что после скрипта идет(в моем случае - тег p с текстом) грузится. А нужно, чтобы загрузилось изображение, далее скрипт завершает загрузку страницы и то, что дальше идет не стало загружаться.

Comment: выше функции image вставь document.getElementById('teg_p').style.display = 'none'; В тег р добавь id="teg_p", стоп, извиняюсь

Comment: Хотя не, нормально. Но это все равно не правильно.  Нужно по-другому решать это всё. Оно работать будет, но это не по фэншую

Comment: А как же тогда по фэншую?)